# sql server in docker using 15gb of disk space

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-your-own-sql-server-docker-image/) to create my own docker container containing a sql server instance with databases and data configured.

I've added two databases, a few tables containing at most hundreds of items each, and a few stored procedures.

The [base sql server image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server?tab=description) is 1.57 gb . (I'm using 2019-latest).

I would expect the total size to be only slightly higher. However in actual fact the container disk space usage is 15.6GB (virtual 17.1GB).

Does anyone have any idea why this might be, and how it can be reduced?

**EDIT 1:**

I've just checked and one of the databases I added is 14gb according to SSMS (tasks > shrink > database > currently allocated space). However it contains very little data (It could be scripted in a 1mb file) so I don't know why this is.

**EDIT 2:** 

Mystery Solved: For some reason the scrript I was using to create the database had allocated 11gb for the log file.

Comment: Please, check the size of all databases including system ones for the file size of them could be set to a high number even though the database itself could be empty.

Comment: I am absolutely stunned that somebody has voted to close this question as too localised - it seems to me that this is a very relevant question for this forum and I'm going to upvote it - it's actually something that is on my radar. p.s. welcome to the forum and don't assume that because you've received a downvote that everybody thinks that your question isn't valid/good! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Vérace. How do I do that @Ronaldo?

Comment: You might want to address your comment to @Ronaldo separately, since AFAIK, only one `@<handle>` is supported per comment. He'll see this one because he's the only poster referenced, but just so you know!

Comment: @YairHalberstadt, how are you determining the container disk space usage?

Comment: @DanGuzman Docker ps -s

Comment: Since my suggestion led you to your solution I thought it would be worth to write the steps to check the size of databases (even though you found those steps by your own) and make this post more helpful to others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database files could be using those 15gb even in an newly created and empty database.

You can check the size of the databases using SSMS:

[image: SSMS]

Or check the size of all databases at once using [Alex Aza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732945/alex-aza)'s code or some other code you like from [SQL Server 2008: How to query all databases sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945360/sql-server-2008-how-to-query-all-databases-sizes) which is the source of this sample:

```
with fs
as
(
    select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size
    from sys.master_files
)
select 
    name,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 0 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 1 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) LogFileSizeMB
from sys.databases db
```

If you see a database that's bigger than expected, you can use [DBCC SHRINKFILE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to reduce it. Using this command is ok in your specific situation though and not a recommendation to any situation of a big database file.